# docker cannot start service from DockFile

Tags: unix, build, docker, sudo, boot2docker

In my dockerFile ,

I tried to do

```
service myapp start;
```

But when I start the container :

```
docker run -it myapp_image service myapp status 
>dead but pid file exists
```

However if I get into the conainer , and start it manually, it ran without problem

```
 docker run -it myapp_image /bin/bash
 bash-3.2$ service myapp restart
 bash-3.2$ service myapp status
        > myapp is running.
```

Any workaround to get the service running from DockerFile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`service myapp start` will start your app as a service in the background. As soon as this command exists, the docker container will stop. This is the expected behavior for Docker containers.

What you want to do is to have the `CMD` instruction start your app in the foreground instead of in the background.

Answer (score 1):

If you put in your Dockerfile CMD service myapp start, but then you run the image you have compiled with it passing service myapp status as starting command, you override the CMD command. So your start command is not executed. If you myapp print something when it starts, try doing

```
docker logs your_container_id
```

to see if there is the output you expect. Or put as your starting command a script which starts your myapp and then it queries for its status. Then, with logs command, you can see if it is running or not.

Answer (score 1):

The container will live as long as command you pass as parameter of docker run, i.e. as long the "service" program is running.

You may launch your server in the foreground, or run a command that launch the server in background (and maybe more things) and keep living doing more things, i.e. monit or supervisord in foreground to relaunch the server if it ends.